# php update node value which has attribute

Tags: php, xml

Hi I need to modify xml using php from exsiting xml content
existing xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" BookId="10010">
     <STRING id="Name" >Test1</STRING>
    <STRING id="ISBN">102399</STRING>
</Book>
```

new xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book BookId="10010" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
     <STRING id="Name" >XYZ</STRING>
    <STRING id="ISBN">7777</STRING>
</Book>
```

Note: BookID should be place before xmlns attribute

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what order the attributes are in ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is here to help you fix your code and help you solve it, not to solve it for you. Did you try anything?

Comment: Have you check **DOMDocument** from PHP?

Comment: yes it should not matter order of attribute.

Comment: I have check DOMDocument but did not found solution to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for reply , I have gone through the link that you have provided  but it did not help me  may because I am new to this technology.This question is not duplicate , but the xml manipulation that I have to do it  bit complex.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($yourXMLPath);

//Loop for element...
foreach ($xml->STRING as $string) {
    //Update value for <STRING id="Name">...
    if($string->attributes()->id == 'Name'){
        $xml->STRING = 'XYZ';
    }

    //Update value for <STRING id="Name">...
    if($string->attributes()->id == 'ISBN'){
        $xml->STRING = '7777';
    }
}

// save the updated document
$xml->asXML('newXML.xml');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing code I have verified but It didn't work for me

Comment: No error in code but it did not update value as expected and one more thing code should handle( BookID should be place before xmlns attribute)

Comment: check with print_r($xml); xml object value.

Comment: Thank you for reply,but print_r printing existing value not updated one.

Comment: Ok, means issue with condition. Can you please check `print_r($xml->STRING);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and helping me in solving issue , but print_r($xml->STRING) also show original value not updated one.

Comment: Yes, print_r($xml->STRING) not for check updated value. This is about check the our problem. Can you please display what is the output here?

Comment: it display output as "SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => Name ) [0] => Test1 [1] => 102399 )"

Comment: Sorry my mistake, use $string->attributes()->id not $string->attributes()->Id. Check after take this change...

Comment: it gives error "Warning: main(): Cannot assign to an array of nodes (duplicate subnodes or attr detected) in test.php line 8"  line 8 has code $xml->STRING = 'XYZ';

Comment: Thanks for your help, I change the code on line 8 as $string[0] = 'XYZ'; and its works for me.Now only problem it that  how should handle( BookID should be place before xmlns attribute) Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes I know this but I'm trying to give you dynamic solution. But now you satisfied. If my solution is helpful to you then please accept answer.

Comment: can you please look into how should handle( BookID should be place before xmlns attribute) Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Hi ,have found any solution to place BookID should be place before xmlns attribute

Comment: Nope, Please add it as new question.

Comment: I have change approach , I am creating DOMDocument and creating each element manually.